# JQuery-AJAX to insert data in database without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

[image]

I have this dropdwonlist, this numbers are votes. In the below code I've put the controller's function where I manage votes. This works fine, with its route-action-template; my question is, how I can do the same but with JQuery-AJAX code without refreshing the page?

The default value of the dropdown list is `votacion.votCalificacion` which is the value of the vote in the database

This is the dropdownlist of votes:

```
<form id="post">
    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
        <option value="-1" selected>{{ voto.votCalificacion }}</option>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the controller's function to manage votes:

```
public function gestionarVotoAction($pysStr, $votCalificacion)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pys = $em->getRepository('PYSBundle:Pys')->findPys($pysStr);
    $usuario = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $voto = $em->getRepository('UsuarioBundle:Usuario')->findVoto($usuario, $pys);

    if(!$voto) 
    {
        $voto = new Voto($usuario, $pys);
    }

    if ($votCalificacion == "-") 
    {
        $em->remove($voto);
    }
    else
    {
        $voto->setVotCalificacion($votCalificacion);
        $voto->setVotFecha(new \DateTime("now"));

        $em->persist($voto); 
    }

    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('usuario_pelicula', array('pysStr' => $pysStr)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is the solution for my question:

The AJAX call:

```
$('#cd-dropdown').bind('change', function(){
    ajaxVotar($( '#cd-dropdown' ).val(), $('#id-pelicula').val()); 
});


function ajaxVotar(voto, pelicula) 
{ 
    $.getJSON('/app_dev.php/es/user/pelicula/'+pelicula+'/'+voto, function(j){ 
        $('#votacion-media-peli').html(j.media);
    }); 
}
```

In the controller's function replace the html.twig view render with the JSON response:

```
(...)
$votosPelicula = $em->getRepository('UsuarioBundle:Usuario')->findVotosDePelicula($pys);
$media = self::media($votosPelicula);

$response = new Response(json_encode (array('result'=>$result, 'media' => $media))); 
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('cd-dropdown').change(function(){
  $.post('path-to-route', {data: $(this).val()}, function(res){
    console.log('Done!'); //or whatnot
  });
});
```

The `data` key I used in the ajax call may need to change, depending on what your $_POST var is in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a resource (like a `php` page) that expects the information (parameters) that you are saving, like: `www.example.com/savevote.php`. Then you use `jQuery` like this:

```
$.post("savevote.php", {"votCalificacion": $("#cd-dropdown").val()}, function(returned_data){
// do something with your returned data
});
```

Anyway, there are tons of tutorials around for you to check. Just google for it!

Good Luck!